# Glassfish UI Console, what is a difference between Launch, Redeploy, Reload

Tags: user-interface, glassfish, action

Hello in Glassfish UI console I go to : Applications -> action, where I have 3 "buttons" : Launch | Redeploy | Reload. Could someone, please, explain a difference between their functions ?

Answer (score 0):

The **Launch** button opens a browser window which shows the links to the deployed application.

[image: launch button]

The **Redeploy** button gives you the option to upload a new version of your web application. You have options to **retain web sessions, SFSB instances, and persistently created EJB timers between redeployments** and to **Preserve Application Scoped Resources**.

[image: redeploy button]

The **Reload** button reloads the already deployed web application, what is effectivly like redeploying the same version again.

You also can find some information if you click on the **Help** button in upper right of the Glassfish UI console.

For information about deploying web applications with the Glassfish asadmin utility (the command line util), have a look at the [Oracle documents](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24929/deploying-applications.htm#GSDPG00004).